# Source Tree increasing badges

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I have the problem that this badges are increasing but I don't know the reason.
I have tried to refresh Remote Status, but it works until I commit.
I have also to say that I am working with a remote server.
Here is a screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 1):

> but it works until I commit

This badge means that you committed 166 times, bit didn't push them yet. You may consider pushing them to your remote to solve the problem.

To be really exact, you have 83 late on HEAD and master, that's to say 166 commits in total.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But if am I pushing all the changes then the value is 0. After I have created a new change, the badge will continue with something like more than 166. This means that the badge is increasing continously.